# PostgreSQL Choropleth Binning

Tags: postgresql, postgis, choropleth

For a choropleth map with six bins, I have been using `ntile()` in PostgreSQL 9.4 to bin each value into its respective group.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT random() * 99 + 1 AS value
  FROM generate_series(1, 1000)
)
SELECT value, ntile(6) OVER (ORDER BY value) AS ntile
FROM cte;
```

Result:

```
   value    |    ntile
   ---------+----------
    1.08    |        1
    1.11    |        1
   ...      |      ...
```

But I recently came across some binning SQL functions courtesy of CartoDB (https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/blob/master/scripts-available/CDB_QuantileBins.sql) and I wanted to incorporate this function within my application. The problem I have run across is that the CartoDB function returns an array at which point I have to now find a way to place each value in its respective bin. Is there a native SQL way to do this, maybe using a `window` function, or should it be done using a custom function?

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(random() * 99 + 1) AS vals
  FROM generate_series(1,1000)
)
SELECT CDB_QuantileBins((SELECT vals FROM cte)::numeric[], 6);
```

Result:

```
cdb_quantilebins                                             
-----------------------
 {19.0055054393597,37.2587848943658,53.8059964138083,67.6696971417405,84.0905840680934,99.8241742462851}
```

Comment: How do you want your desired result to look?

Comment: I would like it to look the same as the `ntile()` result, i.e. the value and then the bin in which it falls [0, 19.0055), [19.0055, 37.258), .... For example, if the value was 32, I would like the result (in JSON, for readability) to be {"value": 32, "bin": 2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is looking for the result in the format of value | bin_number

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT random() * 99 + 1 AS vals
  FROM generate_series(1,1000)
),
bins AS (
SELECT bin, row_number() OVER () AS rank FROM (
SELECT UNNEST(CDB_QuantileBins((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(vals) FROM cte)::numeric[], 6)) bin
) as f
)
SELECT vals, MIN(rank) AS bin_number
FROM cte
JOIN bins 
ON bins.bin >= cte.vals
GROUP BY vals
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly we should `UNNEST` and then find the correct bin for every val.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT random() * 99 + 1 AS vals
  FROM generate_series(1,1000)
), bins AS(
SELECT UNNEST(CDB_QuantileBins((SELECT ARRAY_AGG(vals) FROM cte)::numeric[], 6)) bin
)
SELECT vals, min(bin)
FROM cte
  JOIN bins 
    ON bins.bin > cte.vals
GROUP BY vals;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fcc04/1)

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric > double precision[]
ON bins.bin > cte.vals;

Comment: @hotshotiguana: Sorry, that was supposed to be `UNNEST`.

Comment: I tried it with `UNNEST` but I still get that same error. It is saying we can't compare a single number `bins.bin` with an array of numbers `cte.vals`. I think this is definitely the right approach, but there is just that last little part.

Comment: @hotshotiguana: Oh, the `array_agg` was in the wrong place. Silly mistake really